# How to plot raster data in leaflet

Tags: python, rasterio, geodjango, django

I'm trying to develop gis based web application. I'm using leaflet for frontend  and django for backend. My requirement is to plot raster data in leaflet.  I'm using [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for reading raster file. And here is my View to read raster file upload by the user

```
class UploadRasterView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        context = dict()
        raster = RasterFileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        folder_name = 'raster_data'
        if raster.is_valid:
            file_name = ''
            for _file in self.request.FILES.getlist('file'):
                handle_uploaded_file(_file, folder_name)
                if _file.name.split('.')[-1] == 'tif':
                    file_name = _file.name
            file_location = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + folder_name + '/' + file_name
            data = rasterio.open(file_location)
        print(type(data))
        return JsonResponse(context)
```

Up to here everythings is working fine but i didn't know to serialize this data, os data i can plot raster data in leaflet.

Comment: You could try xarray-leaflet: https://github.com/davidbrochart/xarray_leaflet